# ForkedProcessExecutionException during gwt:compile

Tags: maven, gwt

I run a plugin **gwt** with goal **compile** but get an error from source **ForkedProcessExecutionException**

Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.ForkedProcessExecutionException: Command [[
*javapath* : all java classes from sources path ]]

Maven dependencies

gwt-maven-plugin - version 2.5.1
gwt-user - version - 2.5.1

that is full stack trace [pastebin.com/4xcjxbZm](http://pastebin.com/4xcjxbZm)

full pom file [pastebin.com/P5MMwwHm](http://pastebin.com/P5MMwwHm)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is there really no other interesting bit in the log to diagnose the error? Could possibly be an out of memory error, or many other things.

Comment: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-cli) on project web-ui: Command [

Comment: In question i post source of error, error is LifecycleExecutionException

Comment: Please post your pom.xml also specially GWT compilation part.

Comment: @user3569530 and even **before** the `LifecycleExecutionException`, nothing?! It could be anywhere between the `[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1:compile` line and the end of the output.

Comment: that is full stack trace http://pastebin.com/4xcjxbZm

Comment: full pom file http://pastebin.com/P5MMwwHm

Comment: have EXACTLY the same problem here ...