# How to fix an error from the gwt when deploying an application in java 8 with google-app-engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

With the incoming restriction of app engine to deploy applications with java 7, I need to switch to java 8 my application and deploying it creates errors related to the gwt.

I've tried to change the versions of the gwt plugin, from 2.6.1 to 2.8.2 and 2.8.0.

I've also tried to add dependencies according to other posts on the subject of gwt errors but it didn't change anything.

Finally I tried to deploy the application without compiling the gwt project with this command :
clean install -Dgwt.compiler.skip=true package appengine:update
The app was successfully deployed but doesn't work so I still need to find a solution.

Here are parts of my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
...
<properties>
    <appId>sandaya-dev</appId>  
    <appVersion>9</appVersion>
    <module>default</module>
    ...
    <gwt-plugin.version>2.6.1</gwt-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <compileTargets>
                <value>com.insightos.apps.sandaya.InsightOS</value>
            </compileTargets>
            <compileSourcesArtifacts>
                <compileSourcesArtifact>com.insightos.ui:UI</compileSourcesArtifact>
                <compileSourcesArtifact>com.insightos.leisure:LeisureViews</compileSourcesArtifact>
                <compileSourcesArtifact>com.insightos.data:GenericDao</compileSourcesArtifact>
                <compileSourcesArtifact>com.insightos:Utils</compileSourcesArtifact>
                <compileSourcesArtifact>com.insightos.leisure.data:LeisureDao</compileSourcesArtifact>
                <compileSourcesArtifact>com.insightos.data:GA</compileSourcesArtifact>
            </compileSourcesArtifacts>
          <module>com.insightos.apps.sandaya.InsightOS</module>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
   </plugins>
   ...
</build>
```

Here is the command I give to deploy to appengine

```
-X clean install appengine:update
```

And here are the errors I'm getting from the deployment (I truncated some lines because too long for Stackoverflow) :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.134 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-25T12:29:25+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 71M/817M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.1:compile (default) on project Sandaya: Command [[
...
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.1:compile (default) on project Sandaya: Command [[
/bin/sh -c /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -classpath /Users/martijn2/Documents/oxygen-workspaces/acsi/sandaya/target/classes:/Users/martijn2/Documents/oxygen-workspaces/acsi/sandaya/src/main/java:/Users...
]] failed with status 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.ForkedProcessExecutionException: Command [[
/bin/sh -c /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -classpath /Users/...
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo$JavaCommand.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:485)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:351)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I expect the build to be a success and not to have these errors, and to obtain a working application deployed to app engine in Java 8.
Thanks by advance for any help

Comment: As asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294653/forkedprocessexecutionexception-during-gwtcompile#comment35658724_23294653, please provide the lines **above** the `BUILD FAILURE`.

Comment: Here is the almost full build : https://pastebin.com/h1SbNWKa Sorry I'm a beginner in this field.

Comment: Try with a later JRE?  jdk1.8.0_112 is pretty old: the latest release is _192.